# Detecting and replacing xml from string in python

Tags: python, xml, python-re

I have a file that contains text as well as some xml content dumped into it. It looks something like this :

```
The authentication details : <id>70016683</id><password>password@123</password>
The next step is to send the request.
The request : <request><id>90016133</id><password>password@3212</password></request>
Additional info includes <Address><line1>House no. 341</line1><line2>A B Street</line2><City>Sample city</City></Address>
```

I am using a python program to parse this file. I would like to replace the xml part with a place holder : xml_obj. The output should look something like this :

```
The authentication details : xml_obj
The next step is to send the request.
The request : xml_obj
Additional info includes xml_obj
```

At the same time I would also like to extract the replaced xml text and store it in a list. The list should contain None if the line doesn't have an xml object.

- I have tried using regex for this purpose :

```
       xml_tag = re.search(r"<\w*>",line)
       if xml_tag:
            start_position = xml_tag.start()
            xml_word = xml_tag.group()[:1]+'/'+xml_tag.group()[1:]
            xml_pattern = r'{}'.format(xml_word)
            stop_position = re.search(xml_pattern,line).stop()
```

But this code retrieves the start and stop positions for only one xml tag and it's content for the first line and the entire format for the last line ( in the input file ). I would like to get all xml content irrespective of the xml structure and also replace it with 'xml_obj'.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Edit :

I also want to apply the same logic to files that look like this :

```
The authentication details : ID <id>70016683</id> Password <password>password@123</password> Authentication details complete
The next step is to send the request.
The request : <request><id>90016133</id><password>password@3212</password></request> Request successful
Additional info includes <Address><line1>House no. 341</line1><line2>A B Street</line2><City>Sample city</City></Address>
```

The above files may have more than one xml object in a line.

They may also have some plain text after the xml part.

Comment: Does the xml snippet in each line always follow a `:`?

Comment: @Jack - Not always.

Comment: Then please edit your question and add a few more representative samples of what the text looks like.

Comment: @JackFleeting - Sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a a little convoluted, but assuming that your actual text is correctly represented by the sample in your question, try this:

```
txt = """[your sample text above]"""
lines = txt.splitlines()
entries = []
new_txt = ''

for line in lines:
    entry = (line.replace(' <',' xxx<',1).split('xxx'))
    if len(entry)==2:
        entries.append(entry[1])
        entry[1]="xml_obj"
        line=''.join(entry)
    else:
        entries.append('none')
    new_txt+=line+'\n'
for entry in entries:
    print(entry)
print('---')
print(new_txt)
```

Output:

```
<id>70016683</id><password>password@123</password>
none
<request><id>90016133</id><password>password@3212</password></request>
<Address><line1>House no. 341</line1><line2>A B Street</line2><City>Sample city</City></Address>
---
The authentication details : xml_obj
The next step is to send the request.
The request : xml_obj
Additional info includes xml_obj
```

Comment: @ Jack - I was trying it out on other types of files I had. I have edited the question to include that as well. Could you help me out with that too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sunehaks Please post it as a separate question (per SO policy) and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: @ Jack Fleeting - Sure.